# I don't use Skype - I want to stop the pop-up

Tags: 20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.4. Just recently when I turn on my laptop, I get a Skype pop-up. This is the same window as if I click on the skype icon. I am not wanting to use Skype. How can I stop it popping up? This has only been happening since a recent ubuntu software update.

Thank you all for your suggestions. I wasn't able to find/do the things you suggested, but what I did manage to do was delete Skype completely from my laptop, as I don't use it, and the pop up has now gone.

Comment: Did you install Sykpe in the first place and how was it done? Please [edit] your question rather than add to the comment trail.

Comment: Please [edit] your question by adding the output of the command `{ apt --installed list ; snap list; } | grep -i skype`.

Comment: If you press the left windows `Super Key` and in the search box type `Startup` and select `Startup Applications` do you see Sype in the list? If so, uncheck the tick box and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of it, do this:
Click on Ubuntu Software (the A in a shopping bag)
Afterward, click on "Installed".
Then, simply find Skype and delete it.